# Как поменять масштаб картинки?

Tags: java, изображения, swing

Мне нужно менять масштаб картинки. Я хочу чтобы она периодически увеличивалась и уменьшалась.

Я загружаю картинку таким образом

```
    ImageIcon iiBall1 = new ImageIcon("Ball64_1.png");
    ball1 = iiBall1.getImage();
```

Подскажите, как лучше это сделать, с помощью чего?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Может быть вам подойдет getScaledInstance(), пример:

```
ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon("icon.JPG");
Image img = icon.getImage()
          .getScaledInstance(100,100,icon.getImage().SCALE_SMOOTH);
ImageIcon newIcon = new ImageIcon(img);
```